# Recursion in python: return calculation vs out out parameter

Tags: python, recursion

I "learned" recursion on such examples as factorial where the recursive call returns an equivalent mathematical function all the way down, calculating back up through each return.

This seems more elegant and provable vs using an out argument to store the calculation on the way down.

What are the pros and cons of the two methods in python specifically?

EDIT:

My original question was vague and inaccurate so   I added examples of the different styles below.

```
def factorial_1(x):

    def helpFactorial_1(x,out):
        if x==1:
            return out
        else:
            return helpFactorial_1(x-1,x*out)
    return helpFactorial_1 (x,1)
```

**VS**

```
def factorial_2(x):
    if x==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return x*factorial_2(x-1)
```

Comment: Both use recursion, both return *something* (either `None` or another value) back to the caller. Python has no *`out` parameters*, although you can use mutable objects to 'share' a value with the caller. What exactly are you looking for here?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I clarified my question.

Answer (score -1):

Although I am not a *Python* programmer, your second version looks obviously better to me. It is both shorter and simpler by a factor of two because it uses half as many variables and functions. It uses less memory by storing only one value instead of two in each stack frame, assuming no [tail-call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimisation. And even if the interpreter or compiler turns recursion into a loop, the conceptual simplicity of the second version makes it preferable.

I think factorial is not a good exercise for recursion because calculating it as a loop from the start is no more difficult, and to some even easier, than as a recursive function.